Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}n^{2n}}{(2n)!}$
I have tried substituting $(2n)! \sim \sqrt{4\pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}$ from Stirling's approximation:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}n^{2n}}{(2n)!} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ (-1)^{n} \frac{e^{2n}n^{2n}}{(2n)^{2n}\sqrt{4 \pi n}} \right] \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ (-1)^{n} \frac{e^{2n} n^{2n}}{(2n)^{2n}\cdot2\sqrt{\pi n}} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ (-1)^{n} \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)^{2n}} \cdot \frac{e^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ (-1)^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n} \frac{e^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \right]
\end{align*}$$
I don't know how to proceed. Thanks.

What makes you think this limit exists? Can you show that if it exists, it must equal $0$?

$e / 2 > 1$, so ${\left( e / 2 \right)}^{2 n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Exponentials beat powers.

From your work it is not difficult show that limit doesn’t exist. To avoid Stirling, let consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
then by ratio test we obtain
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{2n}\to \frac{e^2}4>1$$
therefore $a_n \to \infty$.

In general, the sequence $(-1)^na_n$ converges if and only if $a_n \to 0$ otherwise for $a_n\to L\neq 0$ we have

$n=2k \implies (-1)^na_n \to L$
$n=2k+1 \implies (-1)^na_n \to -L$

and the limit doesn't exist.

As an alternative we can also use the bound
$$n!\le \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}\implies \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}\ge \frac{n^{2n}e^{2n-1}}{(2n)^{2n+1}}=\frac 1{2 e}\frac{(e/2)^{2n}}{n}\to \infty$$

From my understanding of your answer: If an alternating series diverges, it follows that its limit doesn't exist. That should have been obvious. Thanks a bunch!

An alternating sequence can only converge to zero otherwise diverges.
